# Color behind the time on iOS

Tags: swiftui

This is my code:

```
struct Account: View {
    
    var body: some View {
            VStack {
                ScrollView {
                    HStack {
                        Text("Account")
                            .font(.largeTitle)
                            .fontWeight(.bold)
                        Spacer(minLength: 0)
                    }
                    .padding()
                    .background(Color.indigo)
                    VStack {
                        Text("Doe, John Jack")
                            .font(.title)
                        Divider()
                            .foregroundColor(Color.indigo)
                        HStack {
                            Text("")
                        }
                    }
                    Spacer(minLength: 0)
                    VStack {
                        Button(action: {

                        }) {
                            Text("Log Out")
                                .foregroundColor(.red)
                                .fontWeight(.bold)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
    }
}
```

If you run the code above, you will see that the indigo doesn't go behind the time and battery precentage. How can I make it do that?

Comment: Look up `ignoresSafeArea`

Comment: I tried using that under .background(Color.purple). didn't seem to work for me

Comment: The indigo is inside the `ScrollView` -- do you want all of the content to go beyond the safe area? Or would it make more sense to move the header outside of the scroll view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this:

```
  struct Account: View {
        
        var body: some View {
            VStack {
                ScrollView {
                    HStack {
                        Text("Account")
                            .font(.largeTitle)
                            .fontWeight(.bold)
                        Spacer(minLength: 0)
                    }
                    .padding()
                    .background(Color.indigo)
                    VStack {
                        Text("Doe, John Jack")
                            .font(.title)
                        Divider()
                            .foregroundColor(Color.indigo)
                        HStack {
                            Text("")
                        }
                    }
                    Spacer(minLength: 0)
                    VStack {
                        Button(action: {
                            
                        }) {
                            Text("Log Out")
                                .foregroundColor(.red)
                                .fontWeight(.bold)
                        }
                    }
                }.padding(.top, 66)
            }
            .background(Color.indigo)
            .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
        } 
    }
```

You would also have to add some top padding to the `ScrollView` since ignoring safe area is going to push all your views to the margins

Answer (score 0):

You should ignore the top safe area for this:

```
.ignoresSafeArea(.container, edges: .top)
```

---

###### Full working example

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Color
            .indigo
            .ignoresSafeArea(.container, edges: .top)
    }
}
```